# Mysql parent child to pivot table

Tags: sql-server, mysql, query, recursive

I want to convert my parent child table to pivot,below is my query

```
CREATE  TABLE parent_child 
with recursive cte (id, name, parentid,level) as (
  select     id,
             name,
             parentid,
              0 level
  from       CONFIG_CLASSIFICATION
  where parentid is null
  union all
  select     p.id,
             p.name,
             p.parentid,
            cte.level + 1
  from       CONFIG_CLASSIFICATION p
  inner join cte
          on p.parentid = cte.id
)
```

**My current output**
[image]

**My desire output**
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the sample data and expected result as text instead of images?  If you could also add the sample data to a fiddle it will be more likely someone will help you solve.  Additionally, why are you doing this - what problem does this solve?

Comment: It's unclear what you want for the second row of that output.

Comment: Have a look at this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)